# Using multiple queries in a single useeffect hook in appolo graphql

Tags: react-native, graphql, react-hooks, apollo-client, gql

I have to use multiple mutations in a single component and using 1 usequery hook; gql query definition is as follows.

Can anyone share the code for encorporating all these mutations in one usemutation hook.

```
const Edit_Profile=gql`mutation{
  changeName(
    name: "navaneeth"
  )
  updateAvatar(
    avatar_id: "11"
  )
   updateCity (
    city:"bglr"
  )
  updateAbout (
    about:"am lino"
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const Edit_Profile = gql`mutation EditProfile(
    $name: String!
    $avatar_id: String
    $city: String
    $about: String
   ) {
    changeName(name: $name)
    updateAvatar(avatar_id: $avatar_id)
    updateCity(city: $city)
    updateAbout(about: $about)
   }`
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem.